# swiftUI - can't close modal screen after force screen to Landscape

Tags: swiftui, ios14, xcode12, swiftui-navigationview

I open a full modal view

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$isPresentedPlayerView){
     NavigationLazyView((MainPlayerView(playerVM: PlayerVM(asset: self.mediaVM.asset), showModal: self.$isPresentedPlayerView)))
}
```

and in playerView .onApper i force screen to Landscape mode
with this code:

```
   func forceLandscapeLeftPlayerView(){
       AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
       UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
       UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
   }
```

and when it try close view or by set isPresentedPlayerView to false or by presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
screen not close!
any idea???

this is close code:

```
func closeView(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        withAnimation{
            self.playerVM.pause()
            self.playerVM.destropyPlayer()
            AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
            UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
            self.isPresentedPlayerView = false
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, this code work on Xcode 12.2 and stop work on xcode 12.3/ .4

Answer (score 2):

This code works. I removed `DispatchQueue`, `withAnimation` and the first three lines. Perhaps, the problem lies somewhere else.

```
struct MainPlayerView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.resetOrientation()
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Click")
            })
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
            UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
        })
    }
    
    func resetOrientation() {
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    }
}
```